# Error:Type 'array' may not be defined here in C++ code

Tags: c++

When I run the following C++ code, got the compilation error like-
Type 'array' may not be defined here in line 17.

```
#include<iostream.h>
class array
{
char a[10][10];
public:
array()
{
   a[10][10]='h';
}
void print()
{
     cout<<(a[0]==*a)&&(*a==0[a]);``
}
 }
 main()
{
array ob;
ob.print();

 }
```

I tried my best to resolve this error, but not succeeded, please suggest the solution. Thanks in advance.

Comment: Is that `\`\`` at the end of the `cout` line in your actual code, or did this happen trying to format the code on SO?

Comment: In the `array` constructor, you are accessing past the array.  Array indices are zero based, meaning they go from 0 to (capacity - 1).

Comment: Please, do a favour to yourself and read a [decent book](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/388242/the-definitive-c-book-guide-and-list?rq=1) instead of some half-baked tutorials. This is terrible.

Answer (score 7):

You forgot the trailing `;` after your class definition and to declare `int` as the return type for `main`.

Also, the correct header to include is `<iostream>`, not `<iostream.h>`.

Comment: It should be mentioned that a plain `cout` is not going to work when using the correct `<iostream>` header, since it is namespaced under `std`.

Comment: @elusive ah, that too :)

Comment: And `a[10][10]='h';` is out of bounds

Comment: And if main returns int, it should return an int

Comment: @Leeor `main` returns 0 by default if no return value is specified.